# In-App purchase uses in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, in-app-purchase

My App requires video calling between two users. Before they can do that they have to pay some amount and then the video call can be connected inside the app.

After reading the Apple guidelines for In-App purchase, I'm little sure that my app falls in the In-App purchase and other transaction methods such as PayPal cannot be used here.

**Question**

Is it fair to use PayPal or other services like Stripe/PayPal to get the payment from user or I have to use In-App purchase?

Comment: It's not a question of "fair". It's a matter of Apple's app store guidelines and whether your app will be accepted or rejected.

Comment: By "fair", I meant that it is allowed or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's [app review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) explicitly require you to use in-app purchases for this.

Specifically:

> **11.2**: Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected.

The exception is if you are selling something for use outside the app, which you are not, so I think you're stuck: use IAP.

However, you should consider IAP an advantage. Yes, Apple takes 30% which is annoying, but the flip side is that users are just one fingerprint away from buying your content – hundreds of millions of users have credit cards attached to their iTunes account ready to spend, so transacting using IAP could not be easier to do.

Comment: You can also allow payments through your own website, but you are not allowed to link from your app to your website. So if you have a commercial website anyway, you can let your customers make purchases on that website and use them in the iPhone app.

Comment: Yeah that's the good thing though, initially nobody wants to share the revenue unless compelled to.

Comment: @gnasher729: Yes, that works great for companies like Netflix; less so when users discover your app through the App Store.

Comment: A website option is not suitable to my requirement. It should be done inside the app.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't use any other transaction methods to provide the calling between the users, you have to use In-App Purchase for that, as you are providing some other functionality within the app.

Comment: Basic service is, one user can call another user to share some experience. This is to be done entirely inside the app and nothing beyond then that.